# Why is Doctrine calling SELECT NEXTVAL in a read-only transaction?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, transactions

I am working in Symfony2 with Doctrine, against PostgreSQL.

Code that has previously worked has stopped working, and only on certain inputs.  The failed cases send a 500 to the accessing web browser, and the following to the logs:

[2016-05-26 22:11:13] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('serp_id_seq')':  SQLSTATE[25006]: Read only sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction" at /var/www/my-project/releases/20160314142327/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 91 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('serp_id_seq')':\n\nSQLSTATE[25006]: Read only sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction at /var/www/my-project/releases/20160314142327/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php:91, Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 25006): SQLSTATE[25006]: Read only sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction at /var/www/my-project/releases/20160314142327/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:106, PDOException(code: 25006): SQLSTATE[25006]: Read only sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction at /var/www/my-project/releases/20160314142327/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:104)"} []

When would Doctrine try to do this in a read-only context?  How do I go about debugging or fixing it?  I have doctrine/dbal 2.5.4, doctrine/orm 2.5.4, and postgresql server 9.4.5

Comment: Can you enable Postgresql’s logs to see what statements are issued ?

Comment: My local won't reproduce the error, and the erroring one is in-use AWS RDS so I would have to reboot it to enable logging.  Not an option unless a lot more things go wrong!

Comment: Local, working, postgresql is 9.3.13